# How am I misusing C++ promises and futures here?

Tags: c++, promise, future

Here is my code, `main.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  auto p = promise<string>();

  p.set_value("Hello, world. ");

  auto f = p.get_future();

  cout << f.get() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
./a.out    
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'              
  what():     
    Unknown error -1  [1]  

15195 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

My compiler version:

```
$ clang++ --version 
clang version 7.0.0-3 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)  
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

My compilation command:

```
$ clang++ ./main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Comment: Where does the exception get thrown?

Comment: for me is working... https://ideone.com/Yh4Hzr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::promise` is part of the C++ threading support, even though you are using it in a non thread way.

So you have to use the compiler option `-pthread`:

```
clang++ -pthread main.cpp
```

Comment: This is very interesting. How come there is no link-time error? Also, what does `-pthreads` flag mean and how is it different from `-lpthread`?

Comment: @r3musn0x I think `-pthreads` (compiler flag) may set internal compiler MACROS or other magic that may impact the standard library headers whereas `-lpthread` (linker flag) will only link the library object.

Comment: AFAIK, `-pthreads` is like `-D_REENTRANT` for the compiler plus `-lpthread` for the linker, but the details may vary per architecture. About why it does not fail the linker, I don't know, but I think it may be related to pthreads being a shared object.